# How to throttle the execution of future?

Tags: scala, future, throttling

I have basically list of unique ids, and for every id, i make a call to function which returns future.
Problem is number of futures in a single call is variable.

list.map(id -> futureCall)
There will be too much parallelism which can affect my system. I want to configure number of futures execution in parallel.
I want testable design so i can't do [this](http://jliszka.github.io/2014/06/03/programming-with-futures.html)
After searching alot, i found [this](https://gist.github.com/kevinwright/4949162)
I didn't get it how to use it. I tried but it didn't work.

After that i have just imported it in my class where i am making call.
I have used same snippet and set default maxConcurrent to 4.
I replaced import global execution context with `ThrottledExecutionContext`

Comment: After looking over the code, my guess is that you first create a throttled execution context: `val tec = ThrottledExecutionContext(5)` Then you can pass it explicitly when a future is created: `val f = Future(/*body*/)(tec)`

Comment: Yes they have done same but when I used same snippet and imported it. It was unused. So I didn't get it how to use it.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing what you did to import and invoke it. Describing code is not a good substitute for posting small samples of code.

Comment: I have edited question and described how i used it.

Comment: You've done just the opposite of what I suggested. You've posted the code that works and described how you try to use it. The link to the working code is sufficient. Post the `import` statement and code that actually invokes the `ThrottledExecutionContext` and uses it to create a `Future`.

Comment: I have used it same way the way you have done in your first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here. Default `global` ExecutionContext uses as many threads as you have CPU cores. So, that would be your parallelism. If that's still "too many" for you, you can control that number with a system property: `"scala.concurrent.context.maxThreads"`, and set that to a lower number.

That will be the maximum number of futures that are executed in parallel at any given time. You should not need to throttle anything explicitly.

Alternatively, you can create your own executor, and give it a `BlockingQueue` with a limited capacity. That would block on the producer side (when a work item is being submitted), like your implementation does, but I would very strongly advice you from doing that as it is very dangerous and prone to deadlocks, and also much less efficient, that the default `ForkJoinPool` implementation.

Comment: So, just one question, For example i have set parallelism 4. So will it start next futures after 4 futures get completed ?

Comment: It will run four threads. First four futures will start executing, the others get queued. As soon as one task completes, the next one will start.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your `ExecutionContext` with `ThrottledExecutionContext`.

Here is a little sample:

```
object TestApp extends App {

  implicit val ec = ThrottledExecutionContext(maxConcurrents = 10)(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global)

  def futureCall(id:Int) = Future {
    println(s"executing $id")
    Thread.sleep(500)
    id
  }

  val list = 1 to 1000
  val results = list.map(futureCall)

  Await.result(Future.sequence(results), 100.seconds)
}
```

Alternatively you can also try a `FixedThreadPool`:

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
```

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try.